# How exactly does mapping get around Governor limits in this case?

Tags: query, governorlimits

I recently used mapping to kind of cache information to avoid querying in a loop. It seemed to make sense at the time -- and it did work -- but referencing it again for another project now, I don't really see how it avoids making the same number of queries. I understood it at the time (I mean, I came up with the idea haha) but looking at it now, I don't see why it doesn't exceed limits.

For example...

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for (Order order : trigger.new){
    accountIds.add(order.AccountId);
}
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>([
    SELECT Household_total__c, Household_Children__c,Household_Adults__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds
]);
```

This code was used to avoid querying for Household Total, Children, etc. in a trigger.new loop later on.

My question is...it still, ultimately, has to query each individual group of specified fields. I'd like a better understanding of how mapping works in this way to differ from how the queries exceed limits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a Map, you avoid two governor limits; queries and CPU time.

There's two anti-patterns to avoid, which I'll go over.

## Queries Inside Loops

The first anti-pattern that people often do when they start learning Apex Code is to do this:

```
for(Order record: Trigger.new) {
    Account accRecord = [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :record.AccountId];
    // Do something with the account
}
```

This produces one query *per trigger item*, which means that if there's 101 records in a trigger, you're guaranteed to break the limit. Conversely, by consolidating your Id values, you only perform one query. This leads us to...

## Nested Loops

Without the use of Maps, you don't know which account relates to which order, so you're stuck with checking all of them:

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Order record: Trigger.new) {
    accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
}
for(Account accRecord: [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id IN :accountIds]) {
    for(Order ordRecord: Trigger.new) {
        if(accRecord.Id == ordRecord.AccountId) {
            // Do something here
        }
    }
}
```

In a trigger of 200 orders on 200 unique accounts, you end up with 40,000 (200 times 200) loop iterations. This is 200 times less efficient than simply being able to look up a record by Id. This leads us to...

## Using Maps (The Correct Way)

```
Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Order record: Trigger.new) {
    accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
}
Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>(
    [SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountIds]
);
for(Order ordRecord: Trigger.new) {
    Account accRecord = accounts.get(ordRecord.AccountId);
    // Do something with accRecord
}
```

While Map access is marginally less efficient than a straight index lookup, it reduces the loop to just 200 iterations instead of 40,000 iterations, which is approximately 200 times more efficient overall.

Comment: Great, thanks for the breakdown! What I'm still wondering is how can that Query get all of the information for all those accountIDs in one query? I guess I don't understand how 1 query can replace all of them required to pull the info.

Comment: @NatalieSpatharakis It works by reducing the trips needed to the database. Here's an analogy. In the first anti-pattern, you go to the store, buy eggs, come back home, go back to the store, buy milk, go back home, go back to the store, buy bacon, go back home... In the final example, you simply go to the store, pick up the eggs, milk, and bacon, then return home. In other words, we simply reduce the number of trips to the database to get the data we need by aggregating it into a single trip.

Answer (score 0):

In the example code you've provided above, your query isn't inside of any loop so it only runs once. You used the for loop before it to collect all of the account Ids so the query only needs to run once when your code executes.

Had you placed your query inside the for loop instead, you'd have exceeded the SOQL query limits (assuming only 1 trigger exists) when it ran to collect the results for the 101st record had you queried for them individually.

In your example code, there's no need to return your query results as a map unless it's advantageous to you for use by any code that might follow your query.