# Still hitting SOQL limits in Batchable Context - how should I rewrite this?

Tags: apex, batch

I am new to the Salesforce platform so this is the first time I've had to proactively deal with governor limits and in particular try to make use of `Database.Batchable` context.

Despite reading the documentation I'm clearly not using it correctly or fully understanding it, as my code (in this last chained execution) is causing me to hit SOQL query limits (i.e. 200+). This, despite calling `executeBatch()` with a scope argument of 1, e.g.:

```
BatchableSetProjectDetailReferences bdr = new BatchableSetProjectDetailReferences();
Database.executeBatch(bdr, 1);
```

I had thought that calling the execute function when operating upon the scope list object automatically partitioned it (either in batches of 200, or if an argument is specified, to per that number).

I can pull the update statement out of the loop and instead add each record to a list object to do the update afterward, but I doubt that will fix the underlying SOQL limit issue, since even with it in it is only doing an update on one record per batchable context operation if called with scope of 1(?), so that shouldn't be an issue...(?)

Anyway, this is the problem code that is causing me to hit the limits:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
    {
        if(doUpdateReferences == true)
        {
            // Point each Project Detail object to its parent Project List object
            for(sObject s: scope)
            {
                try
                {
                    CEGIS_Project_Detail__c item = (CEGIS_Project_Detail__c)s;

                    Integer projectDetail_parent = item.projectDetailId__c.intValue();
                    List<CEGIS_Project_List__c> list_record = [SELECT ProjectId__c FROM CEGIS_Project_List__c WHERE ProjectId__c =: projectDetail_parent];

                    ID parent_Project_list = list_record[0].id;
                    item.CEGIS_Project_List__c = parent_Project_list;

                    update item;
                }

                catch (DmlException dme)
                {
                    System.debug('*** FATAL: Problem inserting records.');
                }
                catch (CalloutException ce)
                {
                    System.debug('*** FATAL: Problem retrieving data from KMUTT server (check it is online...?)');
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.debug('*** Error: ' + e.getMessage() + 'Line : ' + e.getLineNumber() );
                }

            }
        }
        else
            System.debug('-> No Project Detail references to update. Nothing to do.');
    }
```

As you can see, what I'm trying to do, is find the matching parent `CEGIS_Project_List__c` record based on an integer Project ID stored in both, and having found this parent, grab its internal Salesforce object ID so that I can set the lookup reference in  `CEGIS_Project_Detail__c` to point to it.

I had thought that by having this code execute in a batchable context it would iterate over the full list of `CEGIS_Project_Detail__c` records and setup the lookup references, without exceeding any limits. But even calling it with a scope argument of 1, it still goes over.

How should this code be rewritten to properly respect using `BatchableContext`? Do I need to use a different query string in the original `QueryLocator` -- is that is what is causing it not to calculate the necessary scope properly for batching?

For reference, the relationship name of the Lookup field from `CEGIS_Project_Detail__c` is `CEGIS_PL_PD_REL`. `projectDetailId__c` in `CEGIS_Project_Detail__c` needs to be matched with the corresponding parent record in `CEGIS_Project_List__c` based upon matching it with the project id/integer value stored in the field `ProjectId__c`, so I can set the lookup reference `CEGIS_Project_Detail__c.CEGIS_Project_List__c` to point to/have Salesforce ID value of the `CEGIS_Project_List__c` record.

Why is each iteration not using only about 2 SOQL calls if called with a scope of 1?

Here is the full class for reference. As I say, this is my first ever time (attempting) to use `Database.Batchable`, so I've probably got an incorrect approach, and I look forward to any advice you can give me as to how to fix this.

```
global class BatchableSetProjectDetailReferences implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.AllowsCallouts, Database.Stateful
{
    // Context upon which we are generating REST queries
    public String query = 'SELECT projectDetailId__c FROM CEGIS_Project_Detail__c';

    Boolean recordsExist = false;
    Boolean doUpdateReferences = false;

    // Check the total amount of project details available to us to retrieve, set flag to proceed
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        // Finally update the Project Detail lookup itself in the database
        recordsExist = checkRecordsExist(1);
        if(recordsExist == true)
            doUpdateReferences = true;
        else
            System.debug('-> No Project Detail records references to update');

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    // Helper function that checks to see if any records even exist that will require their lookup fields setting
    public Boolean checkRecordsExist(Integer objToCheck)
    {
        List<AggregateResult> checkResults = new List<AggregateResult>();

        switch on objToCheck
        {
            when 1
            {
                System.debug('-> Checking Project Detail List for records...');
                checkResults = [ SELECT COUNT(ID) recordCount from CEGIS_Project_Detail__c ];
            }
        }

        // Extract the last index value from the previous batch operation inserting imageList records
        if(checkResults != null)
        {
            if(checkResults[0].get('recordCount') != null)
            {
                if(checkResults[0].get('recordCount') == 0)
                    return false;
                else
                {
                    System.debug('-> Object has records...');
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

        return false;
    }


    // Sequentially set all of the lookups on the child object hierarchy
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
    {
        if(doUpdateReferences == true)
        {
            // Point each Project Detail object to its parent Project List object
            for(sObject s: scope)
            {
                try
                {
                    CEGIS_Project_Detail__c item = (CEGIS_Project_Detail__c)s;

                    Integer projectDetail_parent = item.projectDetailId__c.intValue();
                    List<CEGIS_Project_List__c> list_record = [SELECT ProjectId__c FROM CEGIS_Project_List__c WHERE ProjectId__c =: projectDetail_parent];

                    ID parent_Project_list = list_record[0].id;
                    item.CEGIS_Project_List__c = parent_Project_list;

                    update item;
                }

                catch (DmlException dme)
                {
                    System.debug('*** FATAL: Problem inserting records.');
                }
                catch (CalloutException ce)
                {
                    System.debug('*** FATAL: Problem retrieving data from KMUTT server (check it is online...?)');
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.debug('*** Error: ' + e.getMessage() + 'Line : ' + e.getLineNumber() );
                }

            }
        }
        else
            System.debug('-> No Project Detail references to update. Nothing to do.');
    }

    // Finally the chain ends
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        System.debug('-> All Project Detail references successfully set.');
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Phil W.'s helpful suggestion, I was able to solve this using the `Map` function.

1. Create a map ready to hold the Integer Project IDs values and the record Salesforce IDs as a class member variable:

`Map<Integer, Id> PLmap = new Map<Integer, Id>();`

Also create/grab a list of the records we are interested in:

`List<CEGIS_Project_List__c> project_list = [SELECT Id, ProjectId__c FROM CEGIS_Project_List__c];`

2. In the QueryLocator `start()` function, iterate over this list and assign the key/value pairs:

```
for(CEGIS_Project_List__c record : project_list)
{
    PLmap.put(record.ProjectId__c.intValue(), record.id);
}
```

3. Then, finally, in the main `execute()` function it becomes straightforward to extract these IDs, assign them to the relevant lookup field, add them to the update list, and finally perform the actual update itself outside of the `for` loop:

```
for(sObject s: scope)
{
    CEGIS_Project_Detail__c item = (CEGIS_Project_Detail__c)s;
    // Retrieve the ID of the associated Project Detail (parent) object
    ID plId = PLmap.get(item.projectDetailId__c.intValue());
    // Assign it to the Project Detail lookup field
    item.CEGIS_Project_List__c = plId;
    // Add to update list
    projectDetailToUpdate.add(item);
}

update projectDetailToUpdate;
```

Doing this entirely eliminates any SOQL queries from inside the loop.

Comment: Fundamental newbie error - you are performing DML/query inside a loop. You need to [bulkify](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Bulkify_Your_Code) your code to avoid updates in a loop and also [avoid query in loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops).

Comment: But if I put the query

`SELECT ProjectId__c FROM CEGIS_Project_List__c WHERE ProjectId__c =: projectDetail_parent` outside of the loop, (say in the QueryLocator string), I have no way of determining the projectDetail_parent parameter, as I need to inspect the record to obtain this value...?

Comment: That said, since you also set the batch size to 1, you should (in this case) only iterate once. Not sure what else is happening here... btw, you would be better off checking if the batch should run before actually executing it since you are wasting 3 async calls from your 24hr async calls limits...

Comment: There are conventional patterns to handle this, which are discussed in the two articles I linked to.

Comment: I will have a look, thanks. When I put the reply above it was before you edited with the links.

I still don't understand why it is failing with a batch size of 1 though, even if I can/should/(will!) rewrite it to be less ugly.

Comment: A useful answer that also clarifies how to do this sort of thing can be found [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/152033/50252).

Comment: What's the exact error message you're receiving? How many records exist for `CEGIS_Project_Detail__c`?

Comment: Just a quick update - got it working now thanks to Phil W. suggestion in the link above referring to the use of constructing a map. Thank you so much for the pointer to this webpage. 

I'll update/edit my original post later with the solution in case it is of use to anyone else with this same problem.